# Javascript Removing jQuery events and getting user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I have a problem with the javascript code I am trying to work with. I am trying to call a function to set an event handler and within that event handler also remove it when the event is called. In this particular instance I am trying to ADD an event handler whenever I want input, then a callback is passed to the function and the code is run when the input is ready. Also at this stage I try to remove it so the callback doesn't get triggered more than once, but there seems to be a problem with this. Here is the code:

```
    this.validateInput = function(NaN, callback) {

    // Wait for the user to click submit or press
    // enter, then if the input is a valid number
    // return true. If it is not valid return false
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {

        // If the enter key is pressed, if the box is focused and if
        if (e.which == 13 && $("#inputBox").is(":focus")) {

            // Print the user's input regardless of whether it is a
            // number or not.
            var newOutput = $("#inputBox").val()
            $("#output").append(newOutput + "<br>");
            // If the user wants the input to be a number then
            // the program checks if the input is not numerical.
            if (NaN && !isNaN($("#inputBox").val())) {

                // Get input from screen
                var newInput = $("#inputBox").val();

                // Remove this handler
                this.removeKeyhandler();

                // Call the code passed to the function
                callback(newInput);

                // Return from the function.
                return;

            // This checks if the user wants non-number input
            // and runs the following code IF the input is not numerical
            } else if (!NaN && isNaN($("#inputBox").val())) {

                // Get input from screen
                var newInput = $("#inputBox").val();

                // Remove this handler
                this.removeKeyhandler();

                // Call the code passed to the function
                callback(newInput);

                // Return from the function
                return;
            }
        }
    });


}
```

For reference, `#inputBox` is an input box, `#output` is the `<div>` I am trying to output to, and `removeKeyHandler()` simply contains the code `$(document).off("keydown", document);`. If you want to see the full file/project, it is [here](https://github.com/codecademy-beginners/text-rpg/blob/master/js/display.js).

The only thing that seems not to be working is the event handler not removing, it keeps going as many times as you add input. If you download the [project](https://github.com/codecademy-beginners/text-rpg/) and open up [`index.html`](https://github.com/codecademy-beginners/text-rpg/blob/master/index.html) you should see what I mean.

Comment: if you want the keydown event to only fire once, why not use $(document).one('keydown', function() {....}) ?

Comment: @webkit The problem with that is that it fires whenever you want to press a  key, but I only want it to be removed when only enter gets pressed.

Comment: yes in this case.. what you did is right, but I've caught your issue in the answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem.. your 'this' you refer to in your code is not in the right scope..

simply do this:

```
function display() {
    var ref = this;

}
```

Now replace these:

```
this.removeKeyhandler();
```

with this:

```
ref.removeKeyhandler();
```

Also in your removing function change it to this:

```
$(document).off("keydown");
```

good luck!

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I'm still a little unsure why my code was wrong, could you explain? Are you not allowed to call other object functions inside another object function?

Comment: There is plenty information on 'scope'.. google up 'javascript scope' // basically the 'this' keyword in javascript refers to the Object in the current context, in your case #document.. I suggest you research this issue, because it's critical knowledge for advanced javascript ;)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I totally forgot about the event handler's scope :)